# PyQt5 method not connected to button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This is my code for running PyQt, however the selectFile method is not called by the button. The UI code is converted from QtCreator. I've checked my objectName for the button is browseCSV

```
import sys
from readCSV import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
import form
from function2 import *
from function4 import *
from Function6 import *

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, form.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # This is defined in design.py file automatically

        self.browseCSV.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)

    def selectFile(self):
        print ("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = form.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually using your `App` class. So you need to do this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()
```

PS: don't ever use `self.__class__` in a `super` call. In some scenarios, it can cause an infinite regress. If you're using Python 3, you can just use `super().__init__()` to avoid repeating the class name.